# Error in sending mails through nodemailer

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api, nodemailer

I have used oauth2 authentication for gmail to send mails using nodemailer. Application was working fine past few months but there is an error coming now. I am getting error:

```
{
 Error: invalid_grant,
 Message: 'Bad Request'
}
```

I had resolved this issue by updating refresh token but this error is occurring again.

Comment: please edit your question and include your authorization code.

Comment: Hi there @swapnilshah! In addition to what @DaImTo requested, could you please provide the Gmail API request parameters and body? Also, are you using [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis-nodejs-client)? Don't forget to delete any private information.